# NextJS turn off scroll restoration on backwards navigation

Tags: reactjs, next.js, routes, next.js13

I would like to turn off scroll restoration when clicking the back or forward button in the browser. I can't seem to find any information on how to do this.

As per the NextJS documentation:

"By default, Next.js will maintain the scroll position for backward and forward navigation."

"If you'd like to disable this behavior, you can pass scroll={false} to the  component, or scroll: false to router.push() or router.replace()." ... the issue is that I am not using a Link or the Router explicitly, I am just using the back/forward button in the browser, so I'm not sure how to go about changing this.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using an [app directory](https://nextjs.org/docs/app) you can handle scroll restoration with [next-scroll-restorer](https://github.com/RevoTale/next-scroll-restorer).

It relies on native [History API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History_API).
A lot of time was spent to develop [this library](https://www.npmjs.com/package/next-scroll-restorer) and it is tested on the production websites. Also, there is a lot of integration tests that handles some annoying bugs that Next.js team did not fix during the past 2 years.